# Pass variable to function scope

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do the following in some other way, without passing parameters?

```
var f = function(){
    console.log(v);
}

var original = f;

f = function(){
    var v = "test";
    original();
};

// the following line is called by 3rd party code
f();  // it errors out here - v is not defined
```

Comment: _without passing parameters_, Global. Make `v` a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Make `var v` as a globel variable

```js
var v ;
var f = function(){
  v="new test"
    console.log(v);
}

var original = f;

f = function(){
     v = "test";
    original();
};

f();//f function
original();//original function also working
```

Comment: can JS engine, in theory, interrupt execution between `v = "test";` and `original();` and replace `v` with another value?

Comment: @MaximBalaganskiy Ya..`var v` is the globel variable .so easily replace value of  that

Comment: @MaximBalaganskiy see the updated answer .The `v` replace with another value on `original` function call

Answer (score 0):

Use can use JavaScript Closures here

```
function f() {
    var v = 'test';
    return (function () {
        console.log(v)
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach here:

```
var f = function(){
    console.log(arguments[0]);
};

f = f.bind(null, 'test');

f();
```